# Combine two foreach loops for better inefficiency?

Tags: php, arrays, performance

I have the following code but I am wondering how I can make it more efficient.

```
        if ($genres){

            $arr = array();

            foreach ($genres as $i) {
                $arr[] = $i->name;
            }

            $genres_arr = $arr;

        }

        if ($themes){

            $arr = array();

            foreach ($themes as $i) {
                $arr[] = $i->name;
            }

            $themes_arr = $arr;

        }

       var_dump($genres_arr);
       var_dump($themes_arr);
```

I've tried putting them into an if statement but because they both always exists only the first one runs. I want to check to see if both exist and always run them both through a foreach loop.  If only one exists I want only the one to run.

These are the array structures.

```
 ["genres"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#1579 (2) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(25)
        ["name"]=>
        string(26) "Hack and slash/Beat 'em up"
      }
    }

     ["themes"]=>
        array(3) {
          [0]=>
          object(stdClass)#1576 (2) {
            ["id"]=>
            int(1)
            ["name"]=>
            string(6) "Action"
          }
}
```

I want to have them as flattered as at the moment they are inside objects. I am then going to implode them into a list for WordPress use.

This code works but its repetitive and some help would be great!

Comment: Please add the arrays and your expected result.

Comment: there is no way to do it without 2 loops.  It can be made less repetitive, but you still need two loops.

Comment: you could get the maximum count of the 2 arrays and only add if it's a valid index for one of the arrays, but that would make the code hard to read, so the possibly minimal performance benefit isn't worth it.  Maybe just create a function that does the job for one object and returns an array.  Pass in themes once to get the first array.  Pass in genres to get the second.  You're code will be highly readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use `array column` because it can read values from ["A multi-dimensional array or an array of objects from which to pull a column of values from"](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) like this:

```
    if ($genres) {
        $genres_arr = array_column($genres, 'name');
    }

    if ($themes) {
        $themes_arr = array_column($themes, 'name');
    }

   var_dump($genres_arr);
   var_dump($themes_arr);
```

Comment: @Philipp Since PHP 7, yes

Comment: beat me to it, simplez

Comment: Wow, this looks like it could be much simpler! I'll give it a go, might need to upgrade to PHP 7 first though.

Answer (score 0):

In this way the easiest simplification would be to introduce a new function, which builds the array.

```
function getNames($arr) {
    if (!is_array($arra)) return false;
    return array_map(function($item) {
        return $item->name;
    }, $arr);
}

$themes_arr = getNames($themes);
$genre_arr = getNames($genres);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would combine them

```
$sets = [];

if ($genres){
    $sets['genres'] = $genres;
}

if ($themes){
    $sets['themes'] = $themes;
}

$arr = array();
foreach( $sets as $type => $data ){
    foreach ($genres as $i) {
            $arr[$type][] = $i->name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**claudio**'s answer is perfect for this situation, but in the more general case you can also define a mapping function, which you then use with `array_map` for both sets of objects, e.g.

```
$mapper = function ($item) { return $item->name; };

$genres_arr = array_map($mapper, $genres);
$themes_arr = array_map($mapper, $themes);
```

This has the advantage of being able to run more complex logic (using a getter function instead of direct property access, etc), if you need it in future.

Ideally, both objects would implement a common interface, so that it was clear exactly what kinds of objects the mapping function was designed for.